# Read-only property for GitHub repos via the API

Tags: github, github-api

I'm working on a GitHub app using their API, and trying to figure out if a repo I'm querying is in read-only mode (eg. this one is: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

I've searched through their docs, and the response, but can't seem to determine if a repo is in read-only mode.

Anyone have any experience with this, or else know of something I can use in the response body to determine/infer that a repo is in read-only mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For archived repos (read-only), the [original changelog](https://blog.github.com/2017-11-08-archiving-repositories/) (a year ago, Nov. 2017) did not mention of any associated API.

It only mention about a [search feature](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-for-repositories/#search-based-on-whether-a-repository-is-archived).

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=archived%3Atrue+GNOME&type=

That would match repositories that are archived and contain the word "GNOME."

So maybe you could try a search for that repo, with the `archived:true` qualifier.
If the search returns your repo, it is archived.

---

A simpler approach, when querying a [GitHub repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get)

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo
```

The answer will include an "`archived`" field

```
"archived": false,
# or
"archived": true,
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but since I'm requesting the repo via the API already, I'd prefer not to have to perform another API request :(

Comment: @onassar "I'm requesting the repo via the API already": then your GitHub response should include the archived field: see my edited answer.

Comment: Ahh perfect didn't see that one. Thanks!